# toPCL and fromPCLPointCloud2

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I have a few questions regarding PCL and ros:

What's the difference between toPCL and fromPCLPointCloud2 commands?
What's the opposite command to fromPCLPointCloud2?
Why can I subscribe to a topic of type sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 with callback of type pcl::PCLPontCloud2ConstPtr?

Is there any source that explains extensively the changes that has been made in hydro version regarding to pcl? All I have found until now  was outdated or poorly explained.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/152416/topcl-and-frompclpointcloud2/) by [SHPOWER](https://answers.ros.org/users/2209/shpower/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2014-04-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Migration#PCL

`sensor_msgs::PointCloud2` and `pcl::PCLPontCloud2` are the message-transport forms of pointclouds, in the ROS and PCL variety. They contain the raw data.

`pcl::PointCloud<>` is the template form of point clouds that allows you to work with individual points in a more sane manner.

`fromPCLPointCloud2` and `toPCLPointCloud2` are PCL library functions for conversions. ROS has wrappers for those functions in [pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/pcl_conversions/html/namespacepcl.html) that you should use instead. These will call the right combinations of functions to convert between the message and templated format.

If you include `pcl_ros/point_cloud.h`, you can avoid doing conversions and subscribe/publish directly with the templated form.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SHPOWER](https://answers.ros.org/users/2209/shpower/) on 2014-04-15**:
when I type in the terminal: rostopic type /camera/depth_registered/points
I got a: sensor_msgs/PointCloud2
then I write in my code:
ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe ("/camera/depth_registered/points", 1, cloud_cb);
void cloud_cb (const pcl::PCLPointCloud2ConstPtr& cloud){
...
}
and I am able to compile the code, why?

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-04-15**:
That's due to some magic in `pcl_ros/point_cloud.h` I believe. How that works on a ros_comm level would be up to someone more experienced to answer.